# How to add divs inside a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to insert a div inside another div using add() of jquery but it is not working

```
<div class="column" id="col1">
    <div class="portlet" id="panel1">
        <div class="portlet-header">1.Feeds</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet" id="panel2">
        <div class="portlet-header">2.News</div>

        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="column" id="col2">
    <div class="portlet" id="panel3">
        <div class="portlet-header">3.Shopping</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Actually panel1 and panel2 are inside a div, and panel3 is inside another div.I want to remove panel3 from its div and place it between panel1 and panel2 in their div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this using [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$("#panel3").insertAfter("#panel1");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This does as your question states, takes `panel3` and places it between `panel1` and `panel2`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `appendTo` which will add divs to an existing div... But if you want to insert in between two divs use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Give the main div an Id say `MainDiv` and use `urdiv.appendTo("MainDiv");`

```
$("#panel2").before("#panel3");
```

Comment: This sticks the literal text `"#panel3"` between the 2 divs...`.before()` does not take a selector, it takes text or html :)

Comment: @Nick i think `insertafter()` is best suited in that case as mentioned by the question poster..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)**

```
$("#panel1").after($("#panel3"));
```